# creating a symbolic link from /tmp

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link

What did I do wrong while creating a symbolic link to `/tmp`?

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/tmp/
$ ln -s /mnt/tmp/ /tmp/
$ ls -alh /tmp
total 12K
drwxrwxrwt  3 root   root   4.0K Sep 28 05:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root   root   4.0K Aug 26 05:44 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 ubuntu ubuntu    9 Sep 28 04:53 tmp -> /mnt/tmp/
drwx------  6 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Sep 28 04:54 tmpDcI8v2
```

Comment: you made a symlink in `/tmp` to `/mnt/tmp`. Did you actually want to make a symlink from `/mnt/tmp` to `/tmp` ?

Comment: I wanted to make a symbolic link from `/tmp` to `/mnt/tmp`.

Comment: then you did it right :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing went wrong. You used the [3rd form of `ln` syntax](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ln.1.html):

You ordered to create a symbolic link to `/mnt/tmp` and place it in `/tmp`.

As `/tmp` is an existing directory, system will create the link with the same name as the target, i.e. `tmp` inside that directory.

You end up with a symbolic link `/tmp/tmp` pointing to the `/mnt/tmp` which is what you see in the directory listing.

---

There are two things that might have confused you:

- the order of arguments in `ln` is: first the target, then the link name
- if you provide an existing directory instead of the link name, `ln` will create a link inside that directory

Answer (score 0):

With assumption that nothing crtical running on machine. We can follow below steps to created symbolic link by following the steps below

First create backup : sudo mkdir /tmp_bak && sudo rsync -avz /tmp/ /tmp_bak

1. mkdir $largedrive$/tmp
2. cd /
3. sudo rsync -avz /tmp/ $largedrive$/tmp && sudo rm -rf /tmp/ && sudo ln -s $largedrive$/tmp

where $largedrive$ is folder path where more space is available.